# Connecting output of script to extract performance

Tags: rapidminer

When I use the `Execute Script` operator, where there is one input arc and this input is of type `ExampleSet` and I run, for example, the one-line script `return operator.getInput(ExampleSet.class)`, and then connect the output to an `Extract Performance` operator, which takes an `ExampleSet` as input, I get an error: `Mandatory input missing at port Performance.example set`.

My goal is to check a Petri-net for soundness via the `Analyse soundness` operator that comes with the RapidProm extension, and to take and change the first attribute on the first line to either 0 or 1 depending on whether this string matches "is sound", so I can then use `Extract Performance` and combine it with other performances using `Average`.

Is doing this with `Execute Script` the right way to do it, and if so, how should I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**: Don't bother about the error `Mandatory input missing at port Performance.example set`
It will be resolved when you run the model.

**Secondly**: It is indeed a bit ugly, the output of the operator that checks 
the soundness of the model, since it is a very long string that looks like
*Woflan diagnosis of net "d1cf46bd-15a9-4801-9f02-946a8f125eaf" - The net is sound End of Woflan diagnosis*

You can indeed use the execute script to resolve this :)
See the script below!
The output is an example set that returns `1` if the model is sound, and `0` otherwise. Furthermore, I like to use some log operators to translate this to a nice table useful for documentation purposes.

```
ExampleSet input = operator.getInput(ExampleSet.class);

    for (Example example : input) {
    String uglyResult = example["att1"];
    String soundResult = "The net is sound";
    Boolean soundnessCheck = uglyResult.toLowerCase().contains(soundResult.toLowerCase());
    if (soundnessCheck){
        example["att1"] = "1"; //the net is sound :)
    } else {
        example["att1"] = "0"; //the net is not sound!
    }
}
return input;
```

See also the attached example model I created.
[RapidMiner Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSmbR.png)